# Spyder won't start in any environment or standalone

Tags: python, spyder, access-violation

Spyder won't start in any environment or standalone.

- In the command window (both conda terminal and cmd ) it doesn't throw any error just silently doesn't work.
- When I try to start it by anaconda navigator it throws "Exit code: 3221225477".

I've tried,

- Deleting the Anaconda and doing the clean installation several times.
- Setting the Anaconda preferences as default.
- python spyder --reset
- checking hard disk health
- diagnose memory problems

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please download and install our [Windows installer](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases) because it should work without problems and it's much simpler to use.